# managing memory in C, 2D float array

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm very inexperienced with C and have to use it for a piece of coursework exploring heat transfer.

I'm getting all sorts of errors with the (0xC0000005) return code. I'm aware that this is an attempt to access memory out of bounds and that I'm probably failing to allocate memory properly somewhere but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any idea what needs changing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(){

    /* constant alpha squared, the area of the domain */
    const float alphSqrd     = 0.01;
    const float deltX, deltY = 0.0002;
    const float timeStep     = 0.0000009;
    const int   maxTimeSteps = 1000;

    int h, i, j;

    /* 2D Array of Temperature Values */
    float T [500][500];

    float dTdt;

    /* initialise temperature values */
    printf("Initialising 2D array...\n");

    for (i=0; i<500; i++){
        for (j=0; j<500; j++){
            if (150<=i && i<350 && 150<=j && j<350){
                T[i][j] = 50;
            } else {
                T[i][j] = 20;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Updating values...\n");

    for (h=0; h<maxTimeSteps; h++){
        for (i=0; i<500; i++){
            for (j=0; j<500; j++){
                dTdt = alphSqrd*(((T[i+1][j]-2*T[i][j]+T[i-1][j])/(deltX*deltX))+((T[i][j+1]-2*T[i][j]+T[i][j-1])/(deltY*deltY)));
                T[i][j] = T[i][j] + dTdt * timeStep;
                printf("%f ",T[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `T[i+1]` - when i=499, this is `T[500]` which access the array out of bound. Even worse - `T[i-1]`. When `i=0`, then this is `T[-1]` which also accesses the array out of bound. The same with `j+1` and `j-1`.

Comment: 500x500 floats is a megabyte if `sizeof(float) == 4`. That's a lot of space to allocate on the stack, you should use dynamic allocation instead.

Comment: Even if `Tdt = alphSqrd*(((T[i+1][j]-2*T[i][j]+T[i-1][j])/(deltX*deltX))+((T[i][j+1]-2*T[i][j]+T[i][j-1])/(deltY*deltY)));` seems obvious to you Today, it'll probably take you a minute or two to decipher after a year. You could use `inline` functions with descriptive names to make it easier for the readers to understand what's going on.

Comment: The first iteration of the for loop causes an out-of-bound read. A live test of your code: segfault.stensal.com/a/dI6qZboYfcIDIOfq, you can fix it and test again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although that's not the problem you're describing, one issue is that you're not initializing `deltX`. Instead of this

```
const float deltX, deltY = 0.0002;
```

you want

```
const float deltX = 0.0002 , deltY = 0.0002;
```

Aside from that, you have an out of range issue. If you're going to access index `i - 1` and `i + 1`, you can't loop from `0` to `499` on an array of `500` elements.

It works for me if I adjust the loops like this:

```
for (i = 1; i < 499; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < 499; j++) {
```

Answer (score 3):

During your `dTdt` calculation you are using `T[i-1][j]` and `T[i-1][j]`. If i is maximal (0 or 500) this exceeds the array limits. The same holds for j.
Thus, you use uninitialised memory. You need to loop form `1` to `499` and treat the boundary differently depending on the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly adjust the loop min and max values;

```
for (i=1; i<499; i++){
    for (j=1; j<499; j++){
```

And you should make comment line to `printf()`. `stdout` takes much time in the loop.

```
for (h=0; h<maxTimeSteps; h++){
    for (i=1; i<499; i++){
        for (j=1; j<499; j++){
            dTdt = alphSqrd*(((T[i+1][j]-2*T[i][j]+T[i-1][j])/(deltX*deltX))+((T[i][j+1]-2*T[i][j]+T[i][j-1])/(deltY*deltY)));
            T[i][j] = T[i][j] + dTdt * timeStep;
            //printf("%f ",T[i][j]);
        }
        //printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I compiled this code on my virtual Linux and it took nearly 3 seconds.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL3Bd.png)